# What is wrong with this code to change colors with turtle graphics?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I have this code, using turtle graphics in Python:

```
import turtle
import time as wait
turtle.setup(500,500)
ws = turtle.Screen()
ws.title('epic turtl')
ws.bgcolor('black')
turtle.tilt(73)
turtle.color('red','yellow')
turtle.turtlesize(5,5,7)
turtle.shape('circle')
turtle.penup()
i = 1
color_r = 1.0
color_b = 1.0
color_g = 1.0
while i <= 360:
    turtle.forward(1)
    turtle.left(1)
    i += 1
    color_r += 1.0
    color_b += 1.0
    color_g += 1.0

    turtle.bgcolor(color_r, color_g, color_b)
wait.sleep(10)
```

I'm trying to change the `color_r`, `color_g` and `color_b` values by 1 each time. However, I get an error: `bad color sequence: (2.0, 2.0, 2.0)`

Why does this occur, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Just to make sure, because it wasn't clear from your original post: you do want to change the *background colour* of the *window*, yes? As far as I can tell, the colour of the turtle itself cannot be changed.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, both the outline color and fill color of the turtle itself *can* be changed at any time.  But here it is clearly the *window* background color that's the issue, as it moves from night to day.

Comment: @cdlane I know there is a pen color and a fill colour for what is drawn; but I thought OP might have meant the image that is used to represent the turtle itself. There are a few images to choose from, but I don't see a way to recolour it.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, setting the outline and fill color changes the image representing the turtle itself to have that color outline or fill, just as it changes what it draws.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize.

Answer (score 2):

By default, the [colormode](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/turtle.html#turtle.colormode) for the window is `1.0`, meaning that that is the maximum value for each of the red, green and blue components of the colour. By adding `1.0`, the values become `2.0`, which is out of range.

The `colormode` may be set to either `1.0` (meaning that floating-point values between 0.0 and 1.0 should be used), or `255` (meaning that integers from 0 to 255 inclusive should be used). Either way, you need to think about logic that will pick valid values, every time through the loop. Also make sure that you understand [how RGB colour works](https://colortutorial.design/rgb.html), so that you can get colours that look the way you want. Changing all the values to be equal will give you shades of grey.

Answer (score 0):

Combining @KarlKnechtel's explanation of turtle color modes (+1) with a rewrite of your code for clarity, I get:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(500, 500)
screen.title('epic turtle')
screen.bgcolor('black')

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.shape('circle')
turtle.turtlesize(5, 5, 7)
turtle.color('red', 'yellow')
turtle.penup()

for angle in range(360):
    turtle.forward(1)
    turtle.left(1)

    color_r = angle/360
    color_g = angle/360
    color_b = angle/360
    screen.bgcolor(color_r, color_g, color_b)

screen.exitonclick()
```

Here we're moving the gray color from 0.0 to 1.0 via the steps of the `for` loop, 1/360th each iteration.